# Products option. Manufacturer's site url

Tags: product-attribute, url, custom-options

I need to additional options of the products "site_url"(attribute) is displayed on fronted as a reference to the manufacturer's website. Can you recommend any good solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just create an attribute text or textarea that allows HTML in the values and make it to be displayed in the product view page.